# The quickest method to delete items inside for - range loop

Tags: c++, c++11

I thinking about this loop:

```
struct tmp {
    int min;
    int max;
    tmp(int a, int b) :min(a), max(b){};
};

std::vector <tmp> data;

for (auto tmp_a : data){
     if(tmp_a.min == 0){
           //how to delete tmp_a item from data from there?
     }
}
```

Of course I can iterate this loop, but I dont think that is the fastest way. (of course I can be wrong - correct me then)

Question:
**How to delete item inside range loop ?** (using the fastest method)

Comment: Given that you copy the elements while iterating speed doesn't seem to be an actual concern. Nor is any approach individually removing elements from a vector bound to have anything to do with speed. Use `std::remove_if()` and `std::vector<...>::erase()` instead.

Comment: The answer is that you don't. Do not use range-based `for` if you need to modify the range. Write your code simply and correctly before wasting time trying to find a faster way to misuse a feature.

Answer (score 8):

Forgo loops and use the erase-remove idiom.

```
data.erase(std::remove_if(data.begin(), data.end(), [] (tmp t) {
    return t.min == 0;
}), data.end());
```

Comment: It would be better to pass tmp by const reference, in case it ever becomes large.

Comment: Okey, but when I have other conditions ? For Example: 

`a<tmp_a.min && b>tmp_a.max` where a&b is a variable

Comment: @ThomasBanderas: Then use `[=](tmp const& t){ return a < tmp.min && b  tmp.max; }`. More general: read up on lambda expressions and/or function objects.

Comment: @DietmarKühl why would you use `[=]` when calling an algorithm that does not store your function object beyond the end of the call?  Seems prematurely pessimizing.

Comment: @user be careful with that pattern, it is easy to screw up.  If you forget the `, data.end()` at the end of the call, the code both compiles *and* works in test cases where only one element is removed.  In cases where 0 elements are removed, it is UB; in cases where 2 or more elements are removed, it erases 1, and leaves the other "removed" elements in an unspecified state (!).  And in a reasonable sized code base, someone *will* forget the `, data.end()` clause.

Comment: @Yakk: In the example the values involved are `int`. Keeping a reference to these is certainly not going to help although it may not do any harm, either.

Answer (score 2):

```
template<class C, class F>
void remove_erase_if( C& c, F&& f ) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  c.erase( std::remove_if( begin(c), end(c), std::forward<F>(f) ), end(c) );
}
```

this is an algorithm that takes a container `c` and a test function `f`.  It removes any elements passing the test `f`.

I find having it bundled together like that reduces the chance I forget the `,end(c)` component, and the two operations (removing then erasing) are so often tied together making them one operation cleans up the calling code.

We take your code:

```
for (auto tmp_a : data){
  if(tmp_a.min == 0){
    //how to delete tmp_a item from data from there?
  }
}
```

and replace the controlling loop:

```
remove_erase_if( data, [&](tmp const& tmp_a){
  return (tmp_a.min == 0);
});
```

or in C++14:

```
remove_erase_if( data, [&](auto&& tmp_a){
  return (tmp_a.min == 0);
});
```

where if we return `true` from our lambda the element is removed from our container, and if we return `false` it is kept.

While taking a `tmp&` will compile, modifying the `tmp_a` is technically undefined behavior.  I consider this an over-specification of the standard.  But if you need to both iterate and modify, you will need to write your own version of `remove_if`: the simplest implementation has no problem with modifying elements and/or erasing them.

```
template<class It, class F>
It my_remove_if( It start, It end, F f ) {
  It target = start;
  for(It& it = start; it != end; ++it) {
    if (f(*it))
      continue;
    if (it != target)
      *target = std::move(*it);
    ++target;
  }
  return target;
}
```

which matches the `std::remove_if` interface (I prefer taking by `F&&`, but compatibility is important), does the same thing, except it explicitly permits modifying the contents of the container while removing elements.

Comment: One question that puzzles me: how can `erase+remove` (deleting 0s, which are ~90% of the data) be actually even a little faster on my enormous vector (of >100M) doing all those huge shifts in most iterations, compared to a hand-written dead simple loop that just runs thru the vector and copies non-zeros to the beginning (i.e. doing _no_ shifting at all)...? (Both are speed-optimized GCC code, exceptions disabled etc.) Can it be just a hand-wavy thing as "because caching"?

Comment: @sz. I do not know what you think shifting refers to?  Or why you think it is expensive?  Remove if simply guarantees everything failing the test is not in the (implicitly) returned range.  Erase just updates the container to ignore the tail (technically it destroys, but int destruction is a noop).  How it does this is relatively unspecified, but it is is usually well written and optimizes well.

Comment: Oh, you think remove if deletes each element in turn?  No, that isn't how it works.

Comment: Ahh, of course, of course!... Thanks for your patience! :) (It just does the exact same thing as my loop, but better...)

Answer (score -1):

One other possibility is to use the following:

```
auto iter = data.begin();
while( iter != data.end() ) {
    if( iter->min == 0 )
        iter = data.erase(iter);
    else
        ++iter;
}
```

Works with all containers (including associative since c++11) and is the reason why `erase` returns an iterator. If it's better or worse in `clearly express intent` compared to erase-remove-idiom is a topic of debate, personally I prefer it.

Note that for a continuous container, such as `vector`, each `erase` will move all items that came after it, which can be quite inefficient, especially if the target hardware don't have pre-fetching, or the value type don't support move semantics.

Comment: This is horrendously inefficient with vectors.

Comment: also undefined behavior as you invalidate all iterators when you `erase()` from a vector

Comment: IT's not only inefficient but also dangerous as `erase` render the iterator invalid

Comment: it might be inefficient, but is neither dangerous, nor UB, It's very well defined, `vector::erase` returns a new **valid** iterator to the item that came after the deleted one, if any, otherwise `end()`